# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $a, b \in G$, how is $aH=bH$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and let $a$, $b$ be elements in $G$. Then $bH=aH$

I'm trying an example and I can't see it.

Let $G= Z_4$ and $H=Z_3$. $H$ is a subgroup because it has the same identity as $G$, all of its elements contain inverses, and the operation is obviously associative.

$1H = \{1+0, 1+1, 1+2\} = \{1,2,0\}$

$2H = \{2+0, 2+1, 2+2\} = \{2,0,1\}$

$3H = \{3+0, 3+1, 3+2\} = \{3,1,2\}$

This shows $bH \neq aH$. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: if $Z_4$ and $Z_3$ are the cyclic group on 4 and 3 elements, $Z_3$ is *not* a subgroup of $Z_4$... $Z_4$ has no element of order 3.

Comment: Actually $\Bbb Z_3$ is not even a subset of $\Bbb Z_4$. Remember, the elements in these groups are *equivalent* classes.

Comment: The statement is true if $a$ and $b$ are elements of $H$.

Comment: $H$ is a subset of $G$ as they appear. But $H$ is not a subgroup because the multiplication on $H$ is not the same as the multiplication on $G$. In $H$ you have $1+2=0$ but in $G\ \ $ $1+2=3$.  So your example has some issues.

Comment: @Nameless Well, there is a set theoretic injection $\Bbb Z_3\to \Bbb Z_4$, so that's arguable.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Take $G=S_3$, $H=\{ Id, (12) \}$, $a=(123)$ and $b=(23)$. Then $ab^{-1} = (123)(23) = (21)=(12) \in H$, but $aH  \neq bH$. $G$ is not assumed commutative and $H$ is not assumed normal.

Comment: @Nocturne I was thinking normal subgroups, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If the two sentences of your first paragraph are to be interpreted as an implication, the statement is false. Let’s look at a simple example.

Consider the group of fourth roots of unity in $\mathbb C$, namely $\{\pm1,\pm i\}$. Four elements in all, it’s a cyclic group generated by, for example, $i$. Now consider the subgroup $\{\pm1\}$. It’s of order two. These will be your $G$ and your $H$. Now it’s not true that $1H=iH$, because $1H=\{\pm1\}$ while $iH=\{\pm i\}$but it is true that $iH=-iH$. So the statement that corrects your top paragraph might run something like:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, with $H\ne\{e\}$. Then there are examples of $a\ne b$, elements of $G$, such that $aH=bH$.